# get_lines() is not working for matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am writing a script while going along with a book for my class. I was given some code and asked to add a legend. The problem is, the method the book tells us to use involves using the attribute .get_lines() to make a legend. However, when I use that attribute I get an error:

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_lines'

Here is what I wrote:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
num_curves = 3
x = np.linspace(0,1,51)
y = np.zeros((x.size, num_curves))
for n in range (num_curves):
    y[:,n] = np.sin((n+1)*x*2*np.pi)
plt.plot(x,y)
fig = plt.gca
lines = fig.get_lines()
plt.show()
```

And here is the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-608174232b0d> in <module>
      9 plt.plot(x,y)
     10 fig = plt.gca
---> 11 lines = fig.get_lines()
     12 plt.show()

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_lines'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ax = plt.gca()
lines = ax.get_lines()
```

By ommitting  the `()` you assign the function `gca` to the variable `fig` instead of executing it.

(Note: `gca` (get current axes) returns an axes object, so variable `fig` is better called `ax`.)